# how to use css module without modifying class names in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am planning on using css modules with my react project and i quickly found out how ugly things can get when one is required to start changing classnames to use the css modules

lets say i have a component using regular css

```
import React from 'react'
import "./styles.css";

const About = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 class="title">CSS Modules</h1>
          <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single dropdown-container" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-static-cooldown-container">
          <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-static-cooldown-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="1 hour">
            <span>
              <div class="icon icon-time-2"></div> 1 hour
            </span>
          </span>
          </span>

      </div>
    );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

but when i am using css modules in a component, i have to modify the class names

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from "./styles.module.css";

const About = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 class={styles.title}>CSS Modules</h1>
          <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single dropdown-container" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-static-cooldown-container">
          <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-static-cooldown-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="1 hour">
            <span>
              <div class="icon icon-time-2"></div> 1 hour
            </span>
          </span>
          </span>

      </div>
    );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

How should this be?

besides the class name, **what about the other css elements/attributes like id?** et cetera. **What about multiple classes in the class name?** Will i have to modify all of those too?

is there a way to use css modules without modifying class names?

I have looked around and haven't found anything, most people just follow along and continue to modify class names but a part of me is thinking **there has to be a better way because that is really ugly**

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to see similar code you can make:

```
const About = () => {
    const {title} = styles;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className={title}>CSS Modules</h1>
      </div>
    );
};
```

so now you only change `""` for `{}`

Comment: very good..but will be a great world if no need to change `""` to `{}` :) but very good answer so far...thanks for this

Comment: how about multiple classes with this answer? how will i add multiple classes?

Comment: css modules create classNames based on components, so you don't need to worry about multiple classes with the same name. To do that, it creates an object that has the real classNames as attributes (hence the styles.className syntax). If you use quotation marks  (""), you will be setting the classNames as plain strings, not javascript objects, and css modules do not support it ATM. It's possible to make it work, but not worth the effort, I believe.

Comment: The way I use multiple css module' classes on the same component is with string interpolation. Something like this:
```<div className={`${styles.classOne} ${styles.classTwo}`}>ExampleCodeHere</div>```

Comment: am referring to multiple classes in the same class name like this for example ```<div className={`${headerStyles["bold"]} ${headerStyles["active"]}`}>Some text...</div>```

Comment: @sowam how do i add multiple classes in the class name? using your answer method

Comment: @uberrebu simply by just adding next elements inside {} like `const {title, nextClass} = styles;`

Comment: what about other css elements and attributes? i updated question...you mind adding how to reference id and the other css elements in your answer? please? thanks!

Comment: just realized your solution will require to have many constants for every html element, imagine like 1000 line of html code, i will have to have many `const` for each html element, that will be worsen things

Comment: @uberrebu we use react to be able to divide all app elements into small reusable components so it is not good to code everything in one component and have 1000 lines of code...

Comment: i use css/css modules, so i use html in my react components...maybe 1000 lines of code is exageration, but i am trying to make a point...though 1000 can very well happen...but the point is...this solution wont work with several lines...agree or not?

Comment: @uberrebu in actual project I personally use [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) which perfectly works with css modules, you can add multiple classNames there and also do some logic for statements

Answer (score 0):

**you can use `Array.join` for multiple classes to space them**

```
const About = () => {
    const {title,otherClass} = styles;

// const className = [title,otherClass].join(' ');

      return (
      <div>
        <h1 className={[title,otherClass].join(' ')}>CSS Modules</h1>
      </div>
    );
};
```